# Show that a continuous complex function $f$ attains a maximum

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the continuous function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ satisfy $\lim\limits_{|z|\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0$. Show that $|f|$ attains a maximum value at some point of the complex plane.

I am looking for a hint to get me started in the right direction for this problem. I thought initially that it might correspond to the extreme value theorem in $\mathbb{R}$ but I can't find a way to relate the two in a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hint: Assume $f$ is not identically zero (else it is satisfied trivially). There is $z_0$ such that $|f(z_0)|=a>0$. So, there is $r>0$ such that $|f(z)|<a$ for all $z$ such that $|z| \geq r$.

Also, we're in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There is an $R$ so that for all $|z| > R,$ $|f(z)| < \sup\{|f(z)| : z \in \mathbb{C}\}.$ Then $\{|z| \leq R\}$ is a compact set, and $|f(z)|$ is a continuous function...